# How to get all countries from google map with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

how can i get JSON list of all countries (autocomplet) in select for example
With AngularJS (http://ngmap.github.io/)?

Comment: Some code of what you've tried so far should be included.

Comment: But if I do not know how?

Comment: An example that includes where you want to make use of the list seems to be what most do in those situations. At any rate, I think @Paula Tomasi gave you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A "place autocomplete" request is a url http with the following format (output can have the values **json** or **xml**):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/*output*?*parameters*

The mandatory parameters are

- input (string with the text you want to research)
- key (the app's api key)

You can also set the location type you want (countries in this case). An example URL would be:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input={*TYPED_TEXT*}&types=countries&key={*YOUR_API_KEY*}

You can check a detailed Google documentation for this here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: Given that the original question doesn't include and code to enhance, I think this is a perfectly fine answer. The question is really the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Paula for response but I tested this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Ma&types=countries&key={YOUR_API_KEY} with MY_API_KEY and it does not work !!

it returns the following result : {
"predictions": [],
"status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}